# How do I remove directories from VScode Workspace without deleting it from the OS file structure?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to have only the files/directories I'm working with in the Workspace so parsing the search results is easier.

e.g. I'd like to able to search just the http and parsing libraries versus all the Library and the test code with contains a lot of duplicate code.

Answer (score 3):

Choose file > Setting

In setting, search `Exclude`

Add pattern(folder) if you want to ignore

[Image Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmJL5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `files.exclude` [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), which will hide the matches from the explorer and exclude them from search.

The setting accepts [glob patterns and expressions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_hiding-derived-javascript-files).